# Fill in a matrix based on whether the index rows are similar or different

Tags: r, matrix

I have a very large pairwise distance matrix in R. I'd like to code cell in the matrix based on whether the row/column names are the same or different.

On a smaller scale, the row/column names would be:

```
individuals <- c("apple", "pear", "apple", "cranberry", "peach", "apple")
```

I would like a matrix with `1` for each comparison involving `apple`, except for comparisons of `apple` to `apple`. That would look like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "0"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
[2,] "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
[3,] "1"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "1" 
[4,] "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
[5,] "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1" 
[6,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "0"
```

I know I can achieve this by doing:

```
final.matrix <- matrix(nrow= length(individuals), ncol = length(individuals))
final.matrix[grep("apples", individuals),] <- 1
final.matrix[,grep("apples", individuals)] <- 1
diag(final.matrix) <- 0
final.matrix[is.na(final.matrix)] <- 0
```

But there's gotta be a cleaner/simpler way. What am I missing?

Additionally, this doesn't work when the row/column names are a tibble, which is how they are in reality. Suggestions for a solution that works with tibbles?

```
tibble_inds <- as_tibble(individuals)
grep("apple", tibble_inds)
# 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```r
outer(x, x, function(a, b) as.integer(a + b == 1L))
```

where

```r
x <- tibble_inds[[1L]] == "apple"
```

if you accept only `"apple"` or

```r
x <- grepl("apple", tibble_inds[[1L]])
```

if you accept any string having `"apple"` as a substring.

I am assuming that your character vector `individuals` is the first variable in `tibble_inds`. In this case, `outer` returns

```r
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
## [2,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
## [3,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
## [4,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
## [5,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
## [6,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
```

for both choices of `x`. This result doesn't match yours, because your `diag<-` call misses `[1,3]`, `[3,1]`, `[3,6]`, `[6,3]`, `[1,6]`, and `[6,1]`.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael Jagan! What if I wanted to do this for multiple combinations? For example, label all comparisons with "apple" as 1, then label all comparisons with "pear" as 2. (A comparison involving both apple and pear could get a 1.)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
individuals <- c("apple", "pear", "apple", "cranberry", "peach", "apple")

m <- matrix(0, length(individuals), length(individuals))

for (i in 1:length(individuals))
  for (j in 1:length(individuals))
    m[i, j] <- +(sum(c(individuals[i], individuals[j]) == "apple") == 1)

m

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
#> [2,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
#> [3,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
#> [4,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
#> [5,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
#> [6,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
```

---

Or replacing the nested `for` loop by a nested `sapply`:

```r
m <- matrix(0, length(individuals), length(individuals))

sapply(1:length(individuals), \(i) sapply(1:length(individuals),
    \(j) m[i,j] <- +(sum(c(individuals[i], individuals[j]) == "apple") == 1)))

#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
#> [2,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
#> [3,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
#> [4,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
#> [5,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
#> [6,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `outer` like below

```
> x <- grepl("apple",individuals)

> +(outer(x, x, `+`) == 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
[5,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
[6,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
```